# make mysql procedure with multiple parameter

Tags: mysql, loops, parameters, while-loop, procedure

I have a procedure that can give me just result (max timestamp) for one tracker, now I have to get result for many trackers :

```
BEGIN
SELECT 
    CONCAT('<KM TRACKER="', ItrackerId,'" TIME="', ITimeStamp,'" MILEAGE="', Imileage,'" SPD="', Ispeed,'" />') xml  FROM info where 
    ITimeStamp >= _date1 and  ItrackerId = _trackerId ORDER BY ITimeStamp ASC limit 1;
END
```

I want to put array of trackers as parameters and get all data.

Answer (score 0):

there are no array's in Mysql, but instead You can use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMP
SELECT * FROM table_source;
```

or `cursors` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Comment: thanks for your replay, how can I get result for list of trackers ?
select ItrackerId from tracker where group ='mygroup';
for each "_trackerId " parameter

Comment: without schema i cant help You.